# How to find if a value lies in between bounds of a histogram?

Tags: matlab, probability, cumulative-frequency

I have an empirical set of data (Hypothetically `x=normrnd(10,3,1000,1);`) which has a cumulative distribution function as follows:

[image]

I also have a set of data `x1=[11,11.1,10.1]`. I'd like to find the probability of finding the values of `x1` if they came from the distribution `x`. If it was a continuous known function I could evaluate it exactly but I'd like to do it from the data I have. Any thoughts?

By hand I would find the value on the x axis and trace up to the line and across to the F(x) axis (see figure 1).

**EDIT:**

```
size(x1)
10,0000
```

So I now have found out how to get the data that plots F(x)

```
handles=cdfplot(X);
xdata=get(handles,'XData');
ydata=get(handles,'YData');
```

I think now it's a case of finding the location of `x` in an interval in  `xdata` and subsequently the location in ydata.

e.g.

```
for i=1:length(x)
    for j=1:length(xdata)
        if x(i,1)<=xdata(jj,1)
            X(i)=xdata(jj,1);
        end
    end
end
Y=ydata(X);

Is this the most elegant way?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much more elegant way to do that using `bsxfun`. Also, you can just calculate empirical CDF using `ecdf` instead of `cdfplot` (unless you actually need the plot):

```
x = normrnd(10,3,1000,1);
[f_data, x_data] = ecdf(x);
x1 = [11, 11.1, 10.1];

idx = sum(bsxfun(@le, x_data(:)', x1(:)), 2);
y1 = f_data(idx);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you for suggesting this method, it works perfectly!